# Windows XP dual screen problems, user account related

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, user-accounts, vga

I have had this issue with a few laptops now and it looks like it is some sort of user account problem. Specifics of the system are:

- Dell Laptop
- Windows XP Professional SP3
- Non-domain member computer
- DLP Projector connected to laptop via VGA

I use this setup almost daily to do presentations, always the mirrored display mode where I can see on the laptop monitor the same thing that is displayed on the projector.

Today, when I boot up, I get the mirrored display at the login screen, but after I log in, it switches to Extended Desktop (like two desktops side-by-side).  Fn+F8 just cycles through all the normal settings except the mirrored display.

I created a new user account on the computer and it performs normally.  Mirrored display works as normal.

I have run into this about four times now and it always can be solved by creating a new user account on the computer, and then all is well.

I would like to either:

1. Find a way to reset the customized settings for a specific user account which would hopefully make this go away, or
2. Find the specific setting that causes this so that I can easily fix it when the problem comes up.

Creating new user accounts is kind of a pain and an easy fix must be out there somewhere.

Comment: Which graphics chipset does the laptop have?

Answer (score 0):

Does your laptop has Intel graphics?
If yes, you can try this, instead of using Fn+f8 or Fn+f7

```
Desktop-Rightclick > Graphic Options > Output To > "select what ever you want"
```

Comment: nVidia graphics.  and the graphics software is no help.

Comment: Strike that, it is ATI.